# JavaScript: Is there any way to do math calculations with unknown variable?

Tags: javascript, symbolic-math

I do not really have any knowledge about Javascript other than trial-and-error experience according to the functions I needed. However I'm stuck with my math calculations now, as I need to be able to do calculations that contain unknown variables i.e. var z="z".

Is there any way it would be possible to do the calculation with unknown variables like a normal calculator can?

A simple example of what I need:

```
var a="a";

var c="c"; 

//a and c should not necessarily be a string

c=50+a-100;

//  output: c=a-50, instead of c= NaN
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not built into Javascript, however something like [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer) may be somewhat like what you're looking for.

Comment: You are using smart quotes: `“ ”` instead of `" "`, which may be causing the errors.

Comment: By "unknown variable" here, do you mean that you want to be able to write an expression involving a variable that *refers to* another variable? If so, then no, you can't do that; that's what functions are for.

Comment: what you're looking for is a way to do symbolic math. This is not a feature in native javascript or really in any major programming language--you need a 3rd party library like Isaksson's link.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others it's not possible to execute the algebraic expression in plain JavaScript but probably you can use [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org/) for this purpose if it fits your requirements. They are providing many features to evaluate algebraic expressions in JavaScript code.

Example output of your expression:

```
var x1 = algebra.parse("50+a-100");
x1.toString();

Output >> "a - 50"
```

Check the "Parser" section.

To do experiments visit http://algebra.js.org/ and start writing code in chrome developer console because all required libraries will be present in their own website.

A Google search for "javascript algebraic expression evaluator" can give you more options.